# Assign a variable to one selector and make last-child work in javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to assign a variable to `$("#investigaciones)`'s selector:

```
$("#investigaciones em:last-child").remove()
```

```
let investigaciones = $("#investigaciones);
```

Can't find a way to make the last-child work:

```
investigaciones.lastChild('em:last-child').remove
```

Comment: Providing your HTML would help me help you a bit more. Make sure you have second double quote on that second line of code. You shouldn't need jQuery for this I will post a JavaScript solution

Comment: @zachjenz thanks for the replay, the missing double quote is an typing error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native JavaScript `querySelector()` method:

```js
let investigaciones = document.querySelector("#investigaciones");
investigaciones.querySelector("em:last-child").remove()
```

```html
<div id="investigaciones">
  <em>
  1
  </em>
  <em>
  2
  </em>
</div>
```